# What is the next pattern in this sequence?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

What is the next pattern in this sequence?

[image: Puzzle]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's

> B because sideways the sequence is 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 2):

The answer could be:

> B, because each image in the sequence always blocks flow vertically (i.e. there's no contiguous vertical white line) and never blocks flow horizontally (i.e. there is always a contiguous horizontal white line).

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: In all the examples, you can draw a line (or path, but a line is sufficient) that goes from the left edge of the box to the right edge, passing through only white squares. Also in all the examples, you cannot draw such a line (or path) vertically from the bottom to the top without going through a pink square. Choice "B" is the only one that shares these two properties (although the other solution is probably the intended one).